# how to make jquery autocomplete in angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat, ionic-framework

could you please tell me how to make  jquery autocomplete in angular js.I am trying to make this type of autocomplete in angular js 
http://jsfiddle.net/dfapnrxf/

or this
https://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/

so I make custom directive .but could you please tell me where I am doing wrong ?here is my code

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/eNZLpp

```
var app=angular.module("ionicApp",['ionic']);
app.directive('autosemple',function(){

    return{
        restrict:'A',
        scope:{

        },
        link:function(scope,element,attr){
            $( "#tags" ).autocomplete({
              //  source: availableTags
            });
        }
    }
})
app.controller('cnt',function($scope){
    $scope.availableTags = [
        "ActionScript",
        "AppleScript",
        "Asp",
        "BASIC",
        "C",
        "C++",
        "Clojure",
        "COBOL",
        "ColdFusion",
        "Erlang",
        "Fortran",
        "Groovy",
        "Haskell",
        "Java",
        "JavaScript",
        "Lisp",
        "Perl",
        "PHP",
        "Python",
        "Ruby",
        "Scala",
        "Scheme"
    ];
})
```

Comment: have you taken a look at angular typeahead https://angular-ui.github.io/bootstrap/#/typeahead

Comment: Actually I am trying to learn custom directives

Answer (score 0):

as you mentioned about custom directives you want to learn, here is a very simple angular.js auto complete directive which works as jqueryUI auto complete widget for server side data.

https://github.com/coded-brain/autocomplete-directive